# Problemas para buscar características del pc c#

Tags: c#

Hola a todos/as tengo este código pero no me encuentra las cosas y me salta un error en los `in` que hay en los `foreach`.

Este es el error:

> Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.Management.ManagementException' en System.Management.dll

Información adicional: Consulta no válida

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Management;

namespace Pr.DatosTecnicos
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher buscarGrafica = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * DROM win32_DisplayConfiguration");
            ManagementObjectSearcher buscarBios = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * DROM win32_BIOS");
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in buscarBios.Get())
        {
            foreach (PropertyData propiedades in mo.Properties)
            {

                if (propiedades.Name == "Description")
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Tu Bios es: {0}", propiedades.Value.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("");

                }

            }
        }

            foreach (ManagementObject mo in buscarGrafica.Get())
            {
                foreach (PropertyData propiedades in mo.Properties)
                {

                    if (propiedades.Name == "Description")
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("Tu Tarjeta Grafica es: {0}", propiedades.Value.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("");

                    }

                }
            }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Bueno, para empezar en las consultas has escrito 'DROM' en vez de FROM

Comment: Dios que viva mi retraso, gracias :')

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta dado que contiene un error tipográfico.